# How to remove unnecessary rows from multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a fingerprint records like this

```
"OUR COMPANY";"100";"100";07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 7:45:54 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 6:01:34 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 6:01:35 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"104";"104";07/25/2017 8:00:06 AM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"104";"104";07/25/2017 5:35:19 PM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"105";"105";07/25/2017 8:47:37 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"108";"108";07/25/2017 8:45:42 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"108";"108";07/25/2017 6:04:00 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"11";"11";07/25/2017 8:57:34 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"11";"11";07/25/2017 5:12:06 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"112";"112";07/25/2017 8:43:56 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Password";""
"OUR COMPANY";"112";"112";07/25/2017 5:39:26 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Password";""
"OUR COMPANY";"112";"112";07/25/2017 5:41:17 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Password";""
```

Formatted:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "OUR COMPANY"
            [1] => "100"
            [2] => "100"
            [3] => 07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM
            [4] => "Check Out"
            [5] => "1"
            [6] => ""
            [7] => 0
            [8] => "Fingerpint"
            [9] => ""
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "OUR COMPANY"
            [1] => "102"
            [2] => "102"
            [3] => 07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM
            [4] => "Check In"
            [5] => "1"
            [6] => ""
            [7] => 0
            [8] => "Fingerpint"
            [9] => ""
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "OUR COMPANY"
            [1] => "102"
            [2] => "102"
            [3] => 07/25/2017 7:45:54 AM
            [4] => "Check In"
            [5] => "1"
            [6] => ""
            [7] => 0
            [8] => "Fingerpint"
            [9] => ""
        )
    ...
)
```

And I only want to get first record for each Check In and Check Out. The record contains multiple entries for each ID like id 102 has 2 Check Ins and 2 Check Outs.I only want to get first record for Check In and first record for Check Out. Here is my approach.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($c == 1 || $c == 2 || $c == 3 || $c == 4) {
                if($d != 0){
                    $dtary[$d][$c] = $data[$c] ;
                }
            }
            if ($c == 9 ) {
                $d++ ;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to I set the condition?

Comment: please format your array

Comment: Also post your attempt, lets see what you already tried.

Comment: i think it should be  *first record for Check In and #last# record for Check Out.*  isn't it ?

Comment: I can't format outside.It's generated from fingerprint machine. I need to format inside php script.

Comment: Run a for loop that eliminate unwanted values.

Comment: you stated that it's multidimensional array .that's why i asked you to format the array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your expected result?

```
"OUR COMPANY";"100";"100";07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"102";"102";07/25/2017 6:01:34 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"104";"104";07/25/2017 8:00:06 AM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"104";"104";07/25/2017 5:35:19 PM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"105";"105";07/25/2017 8:47:37 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"108";"108";07/25/2017 8:45:42 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"108";"108";07/25/2017 6:04:00 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"11";"11";07/25/2017 8:57:34 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"11";"11";07/25/2017 5:12:06 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Fingerpint";""
"OUR COMPANY";"112";"112";07/25/2017 8:43:56 AM;"Check In";"1";"";0;"Password";""
"OUR COMPANY";"112";"112";07/25/2017 5:39:26 PM;"Check Out";"1";"";0;"Password";""
```

You should try [**array_intersect**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

If the constraint is only `ID and 'Check In/Out'` without considering the `Datetime` or the **unique** `Check In/Out` per day, then check this out:

```
<?php

$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","100","100","07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","102","102","07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","102","102","07/25/2017 7:45:54 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","102","102","07/25/2017 6:01:34 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","102","102","07/25/2017 6:01:35 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","104","104","07/25/2017 8:00:06 AM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","104","104","07/25/2017 5:35:19 PM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","105","105","07/25/2017 8:47:37 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","108","108","07/25/2017 8:45:42 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","108","108","07/25/2017 6:04:00 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","11","11","07/25/2017 8:57:34 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","11","11","07/25/2017 5:12:06 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Fingerpint","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","112","112","07/25/2017 8:43:56 AM","Check In","1","",0,"Password","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","112","112","07/25/2017 5:39:26 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Password","");
$myArray[] = array("OUR COMPANY","112","112","07/25/2017 5:41:17 PM","Check Out","1","",0,"Password","");


/**
 * Compare two arrays and return true if intersected counts are the same.
 */ 
function in_array_intersect ($target, $haystack) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if ( (count(array_intersect(array($item[1], $item[4]), $target)) == count($target))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Define a new array to hold the matched records
$resultArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $subArray) {
    // Create a new array with only two columns, ID and CheckIn/Out
    $target = array($subArray[1], $subArray[4]);    
    if (!in_array_intersect($target, $resultArray)){
        // Add $subArray to $resultArray if no array is found in $resultArray by matching the columns constraint
        array_push($resultArray, $subArray);
    }   
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($resultArray);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 102
            [2] => 102
            [3] => 07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 102
            [2] => 102
            [3] => 07/25/2017 6:01:34 PM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 104
            [2] => 104
            [3] => 07/25/2017 8:00:06 AM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 104
            [2] => 104
            [3] => 07/25/2017 5:35:19 PM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 105
            [2] => 105
            [3] => 07/25/2017 8:47:37 AM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 108
            [2] => 108
            [3] => 07/25/2017 8:45:42 AM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 108
            [2] => 108
            [3] => 07/25/2017 6:04:00 PM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 07/25/2017 8:57:34 AM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 11
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 07/25/2017 5:12:06 PM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Fingerpint
            [9] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 112
            [2] => 112
            [3] => 07/25/2017 8:43:56 AM
            [4] => Check In
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Password
            [9] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => OUR COMPANY
            [1] => 112
            [2] => 112
            [3] => 07/25/2017 5:39:26 PM
            [4] => Check Out
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 
            [7] => 0
            [8] => Password
            [9] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks bro this works prefectly. Could you explain me some code so that I could change or modify in future.Thanks anyway.

Comment: Answer's been updated and added a few comments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `loop` the array and `build` the new `array` like below

**1st :** In loop store the first entry of `check In` for each `unique id` Then ignore  all other `check In` entry for that id .

**2nd :** In loop store the `last entry` of `check Out` for each `unique id` So you just `overwrite` the each entry . `if($val['4']=="Check Out"){.. } .`

**PHP :**

```
  <?php


$data = Array(

        "0" => Array
            (
                "0" => "OUR COMPANY",
                "1" => "100",
                "2" => "100",
                "3" => "07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM",
                "4" => "Check Out",
                "5" => "1",
                "6" => "",
                "7" => 0,
                "8" => "Fingerpint",
                "9" => ""
            ),

        "1" => Array
            (
                "0" => "OUR COMPANY",
                "1" => "102",
                "2" => "102",
                "3" => "07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM",
                "4" => "Check In",
                "5" => "1",
                "6" => "",
                "7" => 0,
                "8" => "Fingerpint",
                "9" => ""
            ),

        "2" => Array
            (
                "0" => "OUR COMPANY",
                "1" => "102",
                "2" => "102",
                "3" => "07/25/2017 7:45:54 AM",
                "4" => "Check In",
                "5" => "1",
                "6" => "",
                "7" => 0,
                "8" => "Fingerpint",
                "9" => ""
            ),
    "3" => Array
            (
                "0" => "OUR COMPANY",
                "1" => "100",
                "2" => "100",
                "3" => "07/25/2017 6:02:57 PM",
                "4" => "Check In",
                "5" => "1",
                "6" => "",
                "7" => 0,
                "8" => "Fingerpint",
                "9" => ""
            ),
    "4" => Array
            (
                "0" => "OUR COMPANY",
                "1" => "102",
                "2" => "102",
                "3" => "07/25/2017 8:45:54 AM",
                "4" => "Check Out",
                "5" => "1",
                "6" => "",
                "7" => 0,
                "8" => "Fingerpint",
                "9" => ""
            ),

    );

$final_array=array();
foreach($data as $key=>$val)
{

    if(!isset($final_array[$val['1']]['check_in']) && $val['4']=="Check In"){


        $final_array[$val['1']]['check_in']=$val[3];
    }

  if($val['4']=="Check Out"){
     $final_array[$val['1']]['check_out']=$val[3];

  }

}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($final_array);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [100] => Array
        (
            [check_out] => 07/25/2017 5:02:57 PM
            [check_in] => 07/25/2017 6:02:57 PM
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [check_in] => 07/25/2017 7:45:53 AM
            [check_out] => 07/25/2017 8:45:54 AM
        )

)
```